# Set a different homepage URL in ASP.NET CORE

Tags: asp.net-core

On an ASP.NET Core project I have the following route:

```cs
public class AboutController : Controller {

  [HttpGet("about-us")]
  public IActionResult Index() => View();

}
```

How to make this url the default homepage of the site?

So when I access www.mydomain.com I am automatically redirected to www.mydomain.com/about-us

Is this possible in ASP.NET Core or do I need to do this on the domain DNS?

Answer (score 3):

You may add a redirect rule using the [URL Rewriting Middleware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/url-rewriting):

```
var option = new RewriteOptions();
option.AddRedirect("^$", "about-us");

app.UseRewriter(option);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below in your `Configure()` method (in `Startup`):

```cs
app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "default",
        template: "{controller=About}/{action=about-us}/{id?}");
});
```

See also: [Route Template Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing#route-template-reference)

Answer (score 0):

This is a way:

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult Get()
{
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}

[HttpGet("about-us")]
public IActionResult Index() => View();
```

Answer (score -1):

Modify the "launchUrl" in the project's Properties\launchSettings.json
There are multiple profiles in the file, so modify the one you need (eg. IIS Express for development, etc.)